# Access elements in a numpy array individually

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, element

Say I have a numpy array `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`, how do I do element-wise mathematics such that I could iterate over each XY pair to get X^2 + Y^2 for each pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged `numpy`:

```
(np.array(a)**2).sum(-1)
```

Output:

```
array([ 5, 25, 61])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
    
rows = arr1.shape[0] 
cols = arr1.shape[1]
    
ans = []
   
for x in range(rows):
    answer = arr1[x,0]**2 + arr1[x,1]**2
    ans.append(answer)
print(ans)
```

Comment: Why did you iterate?  Since you have an array just do: `(arr1**2).sum(axis=1)`